# SQL statement in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table in the below format:

```
ID      code   status
-----   -----  ------
1       Dept1    200
1       Dept2    500
1       Dept3    500
1       Dept3    200
2       Dept1    200
2       Dept2    500
2       Dept3    500
2       Dept3    500       
3       Dept1    200
3       Dept2    500
3       Dept3    500
3       Dept2    200
4       Dept1    500
4       Dept2    500
4       Dept3    500
```

My required output is ID 1 and ID 3

Could anyone help me write SQL that will print ID 1 and ID 3 as they have Status of Dept 2 and Dept 3  both 200 and 500 and Dept 1 200

Comment: `1` doesn't have `dept2 and dept3` both `200` and `500`. Please explain the conditions again

Comment: Can you provide an output example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `Conditional Aggregation`.

As per your explanation only `ID = 3` satisfies all the condition

```
SELECT id 
FROM   Yourtable
GROUP  BY id 
HAVING Count(CASE WHEN "code" = 'Dept2' AND "status" = 200 THEN 1 END) = 1 
       AND Count(CASE WHEN "code" = 'Dept3' AND "status" = 500 THEN 1 END) = 1 
       AND Count(CASE WHEN "code" = 'Dept1' AND "status" = 200 THEN 1 END) = 1
```

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/30c582/3)

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is to find records whose IDs match five combinations of `code` and `status`. A simple way to satisfy this would be to specify each combination as a separate subquery and use the INTERSECT set operator to reduce the results to unique IDs:

```
select id from your_table
where code = 'Dept1' and status = 200
intersect
select id from your_table
where code = 'Dept2' and status = 200
intersect
select id from your_table
where code = 'Dept2' and status = 500
intersect
select id from your_table
where code = 'Dept3' and status = 200
intersect
select id from your_table
where code = 'Dept3' and status = 500
```